# Hide divs containing text equal to the selected text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, select

end goal is to only show the divs, containing the text equal to that of the select menu/dropdown. But I think I can make my way there if I could just figure out how to hide them. So I have a piece of HTML:

```
<select id="select">
<option selected>Show All</option>
<option>Red</option>
<option>Blue</option>
</select>

<div class="row">
<div class="option">red</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="option">blue</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="option">red</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="option">blue</div>
</div>
```

and some jQuery:

```
$("#select").change(function () {
var text = $(".text").text();
var option = $("#select  option:selected").text();
if(text === option)
$( ".option:contains(" + text + ")" ).parent('div').hide();
});
```

I feel like I tried various stuff, with no luck. If I set the value of the text to begin with, then it's easy, the trick here is to have the text to look for depend on the `<select>` so that in theory you would just have to add options to that. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Your title and question contradict each other. Do you want to hide or show the text that matches what's selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working jsfiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/dumqz5kL/

And the working script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function () {
        _obj = $('option:selected', this);
        if (_obj.index() == 0) {
            $('.row').show();
        } else {
            $('.row').hide();
            $('.option').each(function(){
                if ($(this).text() == _obj.text().toLowerCase()) {
                    $(this).parent().show();
                };
            });
        };
    });
});
```